# Where to define the implicit val formats in a microservice with Scala, akka-http, Json4s?

Tags: scala, json4s, akka-http

I am building a microservice using Scala, akka-http, json4s. Also using case classes for my business bean classes. My case classes have scala Enumerations (I researched on the scala Enums and aware of the limitations, but this perfectly suits my current use cases).

With this background, when I tried to create a service, I am not able to understand where to define the

`implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumNameSerializer(_ProfessionClaType) + new EnumNameSerializer(_LinkRelType)`

Following is my rough scala class structure:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.event.{Logging, LoggingAdapter}
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpjson4s.Json4sSupport
import gremlin.scala.ScalaVertex
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.detached.DetachedVertex
import org.json4s.ext.EnumNameSerializer
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, jackson}
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, ExecutionContextExecutor, Future}

trait Service {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem
  implicit def executor: ExecutionContextExecutor
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer
 // ?? implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumNameSerializer(_ProfessionClaType) + new EnumNameSerializer(_LinkRelType)
 lazy val client = TitanConnection.cluster.connect();

  def config: Config
  val logger: LoggingAdapter

  def addPerson(p: Person): Future[Either[String, Person]] = {
    try {
      //Code to add person to database
      val resultPerson = Person(propertyMap)
      Future.successful(Right(resultPerson))
    } catch {
      case e :Exception => e.printStackTrace
        Future.failed(new Exception("Person can't be created"))
    }
  }

  def fetchPerson(pId: String): Future[Either[Error, Person]] = {
    try {
      //Code to fetch person object from database
      result = results.one() //fetches the first record from results, if it exists
      //Following is code for validation of the data
      if(result.isNull)
        Future.successful(Left(new Error("FAILED","","",s"""There is no person with requested personID:$pId""")))
      else {
        //Code to retrieve person and return the same as object
        Future.successful(Right(resultPerson))
      }
    } catch {
      case e :Exception => e.printStackTrace
        Future.successful(Left(new Error("FATAL","","",s"""There is some exception while retrieving person with requested personID:$pId""")))
    }
  }

  /** This is the list of operations possible on the person business entity.
   *
   * @param ec
   * @return
   */
  def routes(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = {
    import Directives._
    import Json4sSupport._
    implicit val serialization = jackson.Serialization // or native.Serialization
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumNameSerializer(_ProfessionClaType) + new EnumNameSerializer(_LinkRelType)

    logRequestResult("PersonMicroservice") {
      pathPrefix("person") {

        (get & path(Segment)) { personId =>
          implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumNameSerializer(_ProfessionClaType) + new EnumNameSerializer(_LinkRelType)
          complete {
            fetchPerson(personId).map[ToResponseMarshallable] {
              case Right(personFormat) => personFormat
              case Left(errorMessage) => BadRequest -> errorMessage
            }
          }
        }~
        post { entity(as[Person]) { entity =>
           implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumNameSerializer(_ProfessionClaType) + new EnumNameSerializer(_LinkRelType)
           complete {
              addPerson(entity).map[ToResponseMarshallable] {
                  case Right(personFormat) => personFormat
                  case Left(error) => BadRequest -> error
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

/** Microservice for "Person" business entity. This microservice shall handle the basic CRUD related operations
 * of Person business entity.
 */
object PersonMicroService extends App with Service {
  override implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  override implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
  override implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  override val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  override val logger = Logging(system, getClass)
  Http().bindAndHandle(routes , config.getString("http.interface"), config.getInt("http.port"))
}
```

I also have a ScalaTest spec for unit testing the service, and I am also forced to define the `formats` in each of the test case. Not sure if am doing this right. Hence seeking expert advice.

Following is my test spec:

package in.niftyride.unit

```
import akka.event.{Logging, LoggingAdapter}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives
import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpjson4s.Json4sSupport
import org.json4s.{jackson, DefaultFormats}
import org.json4s.ext.EnumNameSerializer
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentTypes._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
import Json4sSupport._

class PersonEndpointSpec extends UnitServiceSpec{
  override def testConfigSource = "akka.loglevel = WARNING"
  override def config = testConfig
  override lazy val client = TestDatabaseProvider.cluster.connect;
  val logger: LoggingAdapter = Logging(system, this.getClass)
  System.setProperty(DatabaseUtils.SERVER_HASH_TEXT, DatabaseUtils.RANDOM_HASH)

  "Service" should "respond to single id query" in {
    implicit val serialization = jackson.Serialization // or native.Serialization
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumNameSerializer(_ProfessionClaType) + new EnumNameSerializer(_LinkRelType)
    Get(s"/person/${PersonTestData.personId1}") ~> routes ~> check {
      status shouldBe OK
      contentType shouldBe `application/json`
      responseAs[Person] shouldBe PersonTestData.minData1
    }
  }
  it should "be possible to create a person with valid data through POST" in {
    implicit val serialization = jackson.Serialization // or native.Serialization
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new EnumNameSerializer(_ProfessionClaType) + new EnumNameSerializer(_LinkRelType)
    Post(s"/person", PersonTestData.minDataEmptyPersonId1) ~> routes ~> check {
      status shouldBe OK
      contentType shouldBe `application/json`
      responseAs[Person] shouldBe PersonTestData.minData1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is more confusing is the implicit value is picked and not picked in subsequent restarts (without a code change) of the microservice in intellij

Comment: After changing the  `implicit val serialization = jakson.Serialization ` to `implicit val serialization = native.Serialization` the serialization and de-serialization working and at least is not intermittent (works during multiple restarts).